# I am working on implicit intents and my code for map intent is not working. Intent is triggered when a menu item is selected

Tags: android, android-intent

```
  // trigger intent when menu item is selected
    if(id==R.id.action_map)
    {
        showpreferedlocation();
        return true;
    } 

  public void showpreferedlocation()
{

    Uri uri=Uri.parse("geo:0,0?").buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("q","94043").build();
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(uri);
    if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
    {
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else {
                   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Couldn't call " + location + ", no receiving apps installed!");
         }

}
```

when i click on menu item else statement is getting executed and the message no receiving apps installed is shown . I am new to android development.
can Some one help me?

Comment: does it enter `startActivity(intent);` line, or it enters the `else` branch?

Comment: `showpreferedlocation ` method is called or not?

Comment: When you want to trigger the intent?

Comment: when the  menu item is selected

Comment: @VladMatvienko it enters else block